# Javascript - Trouble adding onmouseover dynamically

Tags: javascript, function, attributes

Given:

```
// Positions the bars relative to scale
    this.gDrawBars = function() {

        // Go through all the bars
        for (i = 0; i < this.gData.length; i++) {

            // Check part of it is within range
            if (this.gDisplayFrom < this.gData[i][2] || this.gDisplayTo > this.gData[i][1]) {
                // Is the entire bar showing
                var isEntireBarInRange = (this.gDisplayFrom < this.gData[i][2] && this.gDisplayTo > this.gData[i][1]);


                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id = "gBar" + i;
                div.className = 'gBar';
                div.innerHTML = this.gData[i][0];

                var self = this;
                div.onmouseover = function() {
                    gBarHighlight(this, this.gData[i][1], this.gData[i][2]);
                };
                div.onmouseout = function() {
                    gBarUnHighlight(this, this.gData[i][1], this.gData[i][2]);
                };


                this.gContainer.appendChild(div);


                //this.gContainer.innerHTML += "<div id=\"gBar" + i + "\" class=\"gBar\" onmouseover=\"gBarHighlight(this, '" + this.gData[i][1] + "', '" + this.gData[i][2] + "')\" onmouseout=\"gBarUnHighlight(this, '" + this.gData[i][1] + "', '" + this.gData[i][2] + "')\">" + this.gData[i][0] + "</div>";
```

The commented line at the bottom works fine, but I'm trying to change it to add these functions dynamically.  It needs to pass `this.gData[i][1]` into the functions but it can't, because the i value has no meaning outside the loop.

How can I get around this?  IE, make the function recognise it's being passed a value to use and not a reference.

Comment: replace this.gData with self.gData and use the convention that (rathe than doing self do var that = this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain the value of `i` in a new execution context.

Place the code that assigns the handlers into a named function, and call that in the loop, passing `i` as an argument.

Place this function *before* the `for` loop:

```
function setupMouseOverOut( el, i ){
    el.onmouseover = function() {
        gBarHighlight(this, this.gData[i][1], this.gData[i][2]);
    };
    el.onmouseout = function() {
        gBarUnHighlight(this, this.gData[i][1], this.gData[i][2]);
    };
 }
```

...then call it in the `for` loop:

```
setupMouseOverOut( div, i );
```

This way the value of `i` that you passed out of the `for` loop is retained in the new execution context of the `setupMouseOverOut()` function call, and the new functions you set as handlers will refer to that local variable.

Comment: Do you mean setupMouseOverOut( div, i ); and not this?

Comment: Also is div being referenced correctly in the function?  Shouldnt it reference el?

Comment: @Tom - Yes, I went too fast. EDIT: I updated. I'm not tracking my `this` usage very well. See update.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I get a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined gSetupMouseOverOut.el.onmouseout' error, I don't think the function is reading the array, should it reference self and not this?

Comment: @Tom - With regard to `this` vs `self`, that will depend on what you want to pass to the `gBarHighlight` calls. `this` will be the `<div>` that received the event, while `self` will be whatever `this` is in your `gDrawBars` function. So yes, if `self` is needed, you can add an extra parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a function, it's an event. You need to add it as an event to the element:

```
div.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Note that when you do it this way you don't have that 'on' word there.

Comment: This worked for me. Adding an event listener worked, rather than adding it dynamically as an attribute. Thank you.